# date-fns - exclude locales from bundle with webpack configuration

Tags: webpack, date-fns

I'm using only two locales for date-fns and want to exclude others from bundle, but configuration from date-fns documentation don't work. I tried different variations of regexp and all locales are still budled. Anyone knows a working configuration by any chance?